# php 5.3.6 is php-fpm included?

Tags: linux, php-fpm, php53

I just did a yum install of php on amazon linux beta. (it's similar to centos, jfyi)

php -v reveals its php 5.3.6. awesome so. Now I am trying to figure out if I can package install the php-fpm.

cant find anything specific on FPM. doc says its included but it seems it might need to be compiled. I don't see a yum install php-fpm to make my life easier. :)

so please do guide me on this if you know how. alternatively if we need to compile I would appreciate the complete configure param to help me a bit. I don't want to miss anything essential in compile time.

thank you in advance , need sleep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I eventually figured out that I need to compile. Loaded all the params after much googling and copying the phpinfo for the existing install.

I got the fpm compiled and installed then used the yum for any missing pecl packages since its the same version it worked fine.

one issue remained is the init script for fpm in the source does not really work. it picks up the param and env paths etc all ok but something is not right so it just fails to work.

usually a pecl install is available in yum. But not always.

Comment: thanks for that pointer. i thought i would allow for some more feedback on my answer. and now new answer has shown up too. If other answers evolve to be better than mine I would mark it so. or so i hope... so good to wait, no?

Answer (score 0):

Once compiled you need to check the user/group defined within the configuration file as well as modifying some options like the dynamic workers or the php options. The later caused me some headache as i had forgotten to remove them.
Did you check the fpm error log ? What errors are reported ?

Comment: i got problems with the workers as well. I had to edit the php-fpm.conf files as apparently default values dont work correctly (as of 5.3.6) so while it works now the init script does not work, it claims to not find the pid file... then attempts to start and shows fail. Even though php-fpm process is started.
interesting thing you mentioned regarding workers. would you care to share an example of these options specified during compile?

noe more problem: despite having specified--disable-pdo --disable-phar etc it continues to compile and add it. same thing for  --without-sqlite, has no effect

Comment: You must check both the php-fpm conf file as well as the php.ini used by fpm. When compiling did you specify the path to the php.ini file ?

Comment: yes what you said I  have already done. As I mentioned in my own answer I got the FPM working by manually editing the conf files. However the Init script does not work properly. Would you happen to have the parameters you used to compile? I could try it out on an instance and work from there. am using on CentOS-like os and I can modify the params to suit my setup, thanks